# How to force cbindgen to expand macros?

Tags: rust

I have following rust code.

```
macro_rules! expose {
    ($($name:ident)*) => {
        $(
            #[no_mangle]
            pub extern "C" fn $name() -> bool {
                true
            }
        )*
    }
}

expose! {
    asd
    dsa
    fgh
    jkl
}

/** header.h
should contain
bool asd();
bool dsa();
bool fgh();
bool jkl();
**/
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

How do I see in cbindgen's output all functions generated by the macro?
One way how to do that I've found is `cargo expand` before and after process output with cbindgen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `parse.expand.crates` in the `cbindgen.toml`:

```
[parse.expand]
# A list of crate names that should be run through `cargo expand` before
# parsing to expand any macros. Note that if a crate is named here, it
# will always be parsed, even if the blacklist/whitelist says it shouldn't be.
#
# default: []
crates = ["your_crate_name"]
```

excerpt from [cbindgen docs](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/blob/master/docs.md#cbindgentoml)